# Playing one sound after another with pauses from random generated pattern

Tags: java, android

I want to create app in which after i press one button it will generate me pattern and for another button it will play this pattern- every letter will mean diffrent sound (for now i used morse sounds). While pattern is generated correctly and sounds plays, the sounds are playing almost all at the time. I thought it might be because of speed with which android plays them, so i tried to add silence.mp3 file( 1s silence) between them, but it still sounds like everything is playing at once

```
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

import java.util.Random;
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Consts Cons = new Consts();
    final int patternLenght=4;
    String pattern;
    int[] soundArray=new int[patternLenght*2];
    MediaPlayer[] mp=new MediaPlayer[patternLenght*2];
    private String GeneratePattern(int lenght) {
        String patterngen = "";
        Random rand = new Random();
        for (int i = 0; i < lenght; i++) {
            int n = rand.nextInt(2); //0-1
            String temp = Cons.ALFABET[n];
            patterngen = patterngen + temp;
        }
        pattern=patterngen;
        MakeSoundArray();
        return patterngen;
    }
    private  void MakeSoundArray(){
        for (int i = 0; i < pattern.length(); i++) {
            char sound = pattern.charAt(i);
            if(sound=='A')soundArray[i]=R.raw.a_sound_morse;
            if(sound=='B')soundArray[i]=R.raw.b_sound_morse;


            soundArray[i+1]=R.raw.silence;

        }

    }

        private void PlayFile() {


        if (pattern == null)return;

            for (int i = 0; i < pattern.length(); i++) {
            mp[i]=MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this,soundArray[i]);

            }
            for(int i=0;i<patternLenght-1;i++){
                mp[i].setNextMediaPlayer(mp[i+1]);
            }

            for(int i=0;i<patternLenght;i++){
                mp[i].start();
            }

    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        Button start = findViewById(R.id.make_pattern);
        start.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                pattern = GeneratePattern(patternLenght);
                Log.i("Pattern", pattern);
            }
        });
        //Odtwarzanie patternu
        Button playpattern = findViewById(R.id.playPattern);
        playpattern.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                PlayFile();
            }
        });

    }


}
```

Consts Class

```
public class Consts {

    final String ALFABET[]={"A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I"};

}
```

I tried using AudioManager and ToneGenerator to just create beeps, but they still played simultaneously. I tried using OnCompletionListiner  but couldnt bind every pattern character automaticly using function/loop.

Comment: You are starting all 8 players simultaneously in your `for` loop.

Comment: Then how can i start them not simultaneously?

Comment: Well think about it. In the previous loop, you chained all the players together using `setNextMediaPlayer()`. In other words, as the n-th MediaPlayer finishes, the (n+1)th MediaPlayer starts up. Weren't you thinking of just starting it at `mp[0]`?

Comment: God Damn, i think i was thinking about it too much. Thank you very much greeble31, it worked

Comment: Happens to me all the time. Have fun.